# Need example code of an expandableListView on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

I need a working example of an application that uses an expandableListView. I have no idea how to set data in it. I have tried with the new ArrayAdapter(...). But I can't figure out how to create the correct parameters.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I've used some code already but it needs some kind of resource out of the R, R.layout.simple_list_1. It's not declared anywhere but still most of the people seem to have it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API demos are a great source](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html) for these basic examples

> I've used some code already but it needs some kind of resource out of the R, R.layout.simple_list_1. It's not declared anywhere

That is a reference to an built-in XML layout document that is part of the Android OS.  Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` if you cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

check this one :

[expandable list](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html)

hope it helps!